# Custom the background for polygon in Syncfusion Blazor maps

Tags: blazor, syncfusion

Is it possible to custom the background for polygon in Syncfusion  Blazor maps, to be like shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom background to the polygon shape of a map in the sample itself by setting the reference of the SVG pattern element as fill color to the layer of the maps component. The “**id**”  attribute of the SVG pattern must be set to the “**Fill**” property of the “**MapsShapeSettings**” of the “**MapsLayer**”. Please find the code snippet for the same below.

**Code Snippet:**

```
<svg>
    <defs xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg><pattern id="lines" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="2" height="5" patternTransform="rotate(60)"><line x1="0" y="0" x2="0" y2="11" stroke="#194d33" stroke-width="2" /></pattern></defs>
</svg>

<SfMaps ID="Maps">
    //..
   <MapsLayers>
     //..
        <MapsLayer Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Maps.Type.SubLayer" ShapeData='new {dataOptions= "simplegeo.json"}' TValue="string">
            <MapsShapeSettings Fill="url(#lines)">
                <MapsShapeBorder Color="Red" Width="5"></MapsShapeBorder>
            </MapsShapeSettings>
        </MapsLayer>
    </MapsLayers>
</SfMaps>
```

You can find the sample from the link below.
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/MapsBlazor1014000297

[image: Custom background to the polygon shape of the Maps]

Comment: It works , Thank you so much.

But can I get the color dynamically from the datasource ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Maps component, you can set the colors from the data source to the shapes in the map layer using "**ColorValuePath**" property of the "**MapsShapeSettings**" tag. You need to set the field name (that holds color values) from the data source as value in the “**ColorValuePath**” property. Please find the code snippet for the same below.

**Code Snippet:**

```
<SfMaps ID="Maps" @ref="maps">
    <MapsLayers>
    //..
        <MapsLayer Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Maps.Type.SubLayer" DataSource="CustomShapeDataSource" ShapeData='new {dataOptions= "simplegeo.json"}' TValue="CustomShapeData" ShapeDataPath="Name" ShapePropertyPath='new string[]{"name"}'>
            <MapsShapeSettings Fill="@ShapeFill" ColorValuePath=@ColorPath>
            </MapsShapeSettings>
        </MapsLayer>
    </MapsLayers>
</SfMaps>

 

@code {
    SfMaps maps;
    public string ShapeFill = "url(#lines)";
    public string ColorPath = string.Empty;
    public List<CustomShapeData> CustomShapeDataSource = new 
         List<CustomShapeData>{
            new CustomShapeData { Name= "shapeone", InitialColor = "pink" }
         };
 
    void ChangeColor()
    {
        ShapeFill = string.Empty;
        ColorPath = "InitialColor";
    }
}​
```

If you need to change the color of a single shape dynamically in the Maps, you need to set the color value in the desired object in the data source and call the “Refresh” method of the Maps component.  Please find the code snippet for the same below.

**Code Snippet:**

```
<SfMaps ID="Maps" @ref="maps">
   <MapsLayers>
    //..
   <MapsLayer Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Maps.Type.SubLayer" DataSource="CustomShapeDataSource" ShapeData='new {dataOptions= "simplegeo.json"}' TValue="CustomShapeData" ShapeDataPath="Name" ShapePropertyPath='new string[]{"name"}'>
    <MapsShapeSettings Fill="@ShapeFill" ColorValuePath=@ColorPath>
    </MapsShapeSettings>
   </MapsLayer>
 </MapsLayers>
</SfMaps>

@code {
    SfMaps maps;
    public string ShapeFill = "url(#lines)";
    public string ColorPath = string.Empty;
    public List<CustomShapeData> CustomShapeDataSource = new 
         List<CustomShapeData>{
         new CustomShapeData { Name= "shapeone", InitialColor = "pink" }
    };

    void ChangeColor()
    {
        ShapeFill = string.Empty;
        ColorPath = "InitialColor";
    }

    void ChangeSpecificColor()
    {
        CustomShapeDataSource[2].InitialColor = "#728FCE";
        maps.Refresh();
    }
}​
```

You can find the sample application to demonstrate the same and its video from the below links.

**Sample:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/MapsBlazor186567838

**Video:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/shapecolor-761752925